# Cannot save selected checkbox to variable

Tags: javafx

I am a problem with javafx. I have GridPane with about 40 CheckBoxes. I need make user can select only one CheckBox and selected CheckBox is saved to a variable.

This is method for work with checkboxes:

```
    public static class createBet {
        public static CheckBox bet;

        public static CheckBox isBet(CheckBox[] group, int finalI, AnchorPane resultBlock) {
            for (CheckBox j : group) {
                if (j.equals(bet)) {
                    j.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            ObservableList resultLabels = resultBlock.getChildren();
            Label label_num = (Label)resultLabels.get(0);
            Label label_win = (Label)resultLabels.get(1);

            if (group[finalI].isSelected()) {
                bet = group[finalI];
                resultBlock.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
                label_num.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
                label_win.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
            }
            else {
                bet = null;
                resultBlock.setStyle("-fx-border-color: gray");
                label_num.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: gray");
                label_win.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: gray");
            }

            return bet;
        }
    }
```

This is a class for final variables:

```
    public class bets {
        public CheckBox numberBet = null;
        public CheckBox colorBet = null;
        public CheckBox evenBet = null;
    }
```

There I use this classes:

```
       //(block with variables and links to FXML)

        createBet bet = new createBet();
        bets bets = new bets();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersGroup.length; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            numbersGroup[i].selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    bets.numberBet = createBet.isBet(numbersGroup, finalI, resultNum);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Checkboxes are selected correctly, but variables for selected CheckBox (class bets) always equal null.

UPD. I comment class `createBet` and add code from it to the `public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)`. It not change the situation - variable `bets.numberBet` is changing in the listener only, outside it this variable allways equals `null`. 
I want use `numberBet` in the whole code, it's main problem.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: `createBet` is a poor choice of class name. Class names by convnetions are nouns. Furthermore I'll do kleos job here and tell you about the fact that according to java naming conventions type names start with an uppercase letter. The way you designed the `createBet` class there's no point in creating an instance: every single member is static (duh) which means creating the instance serves no purpose other than makine it harder for the reader of your code to determine that a `static` method is called.

Comment: Furthermore is it possible for `bet` being non-null and not part of `group`? If so why loop through `group` instead of doing `if (bet != null) { bet.setSelected(false); }`?

Comment: @kleopatra, I read this rules, bun doesn't understand, what's bad :( Need comments in the code?

Comment: @fabian, OK, I understand about naming :) I learn by guides in internet and mayby miss this rules.

Comment: @fabian, @fabian, About loop - your code doesn't work. I need to make `false` a Checkbox in the `group`, not `bet`.  And my main problem is I cannot set bet to `numberBet` for using it outside the action, `numberBet` always equal null.

Comment: As already mentioned in the manual, a MVCE is a new program (kept as simple as possible) that exactly replicates your problem. This way we can help you better, and we can analyze the problem more precisely (since we can run it ourselves) instead of just "guessing" what the error might be.

Comment: @poisn, o, thanks, I understand. I think, this problem already solved, but I will remember for future.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem. I DON'T set varbable `numberBet` with method `isBet`. `isBet`work for change CheckBoxes and activation for block `resultNum` only.
Variables i set in inner action, where thei are used.

new version of class:

```
public class Bet {
        private CheckBox bet;

        public void forBet(CheckBox[] group, int finalI, AnchorPane resultBlock) {
            for (CheckBox j : group) {
                if (j.equals(bet)) {
                    j.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            ObservableList resultLabels = resultBlock.getChildren();
            Label label_num = (Label)resultLabels.get(0);
            Label label_win = (Label)resultLabels.get(1);

            if (group[finalI].isSelected()) {
                bet = group[finalI];
                resultBlock.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
                label_num.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
                label_win.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
            }
            else {
                bet = null;
                resultBlock.setStyle("-fx-border-color: gray");
                label_num.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: gray");
                label_win.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: gray");
            }
        }

        public CheckBox startBet(CheckBox[] group) {
            for (CheckBox i : group){
                if (i.isSelected()) {
                    bet = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return bet;
        }
    }
```

variables:

```
public CheckBox numberBet = null;
public CheckBox colorBet = null;
public CheckBox evenBet = null;
```

Using for methods:

```
        Bet Bet = new Bet();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersGroup.length; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            numbersGroup[i].selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    Bet.forBet(numbersGroup, finalI,resultNum);
                }
            });
        }

        btn_start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                numberBet = Bet.startBet(numbersGroup);
                System.out.println(numberBet);
            }
        });
```

I think, it's resolve my issue.